# How to call upon dynamically created objects

Tags: vb.net

Okay so here is what I have:

```
    Do
        x = x + 1
        Dim myTxt As New TextBox
        myTxt.Name = ("TbMat" & x.ToString())
        myTxt.Location = New Point(13, 13 + (x * 37))
        myTxt.Tag = "For DB"
        myTxt.Visible = True
        Button2.Location = New Point(13, 39 + (x * 37))
        If x = 5 Then
            Button1.Dispose()
        End If
        Me.Controls.Add(myTxt)
        Me.Refresh()
    Loop Until x >= 1
```

It's my makeshift way of letting the user add a textbox by clicking a button. I am new to programming so this may be an easy fix but here is my question... when the user adds a textbox I want the first one to be "TbMat1" so I would assume to call upon it to get information I would just use, for example, textbox1.text=TbMat1.text. When I do this, it says TbMat1 is not declared, which is obvious since it isn't created yet.

I need help pulling information from the new textboxes to other textboxes, and later I will figure out exporting. Thanks.

Comment: you can use something like this `Me.FindControl("TbMat" & x.ToString())`. this would return the textbox instance as an object so you have to cast it to TextBox before using.

Comment: Winforms? ASP.Net? etc?

Comment: Welcome to SO, user2879745.

Answer (score 2):

When you created the control, you created it as `myTxt` which is its object reference.  So in the procedure where that code block exists this would work:

```
 SomeOtherTB.Text = myTxt.Text
```

The name is `just` the name, not an object reference or 'handle'.  Further, once the code exits that procedure `myTxt` goes out of scope because that is where it was declared (`Dim` or `Private|Friend|Public`).  To access your new control elsewhere:

```
SomeOtherTB.Text = Me.Controls("TbMat1")       ' or "TbMat" & x.ToString()
```

OR create a new object ref if you want:

```
Friend myTB AS TextBox                        ' module level at least

myTb = Me.Controls("TbMat1")
```

The latter might not be practical if you are making lots of them.